# Service Fabric cluster. Statefull service. Service Bus queue usage

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azure-servicebus-queues

Full disclosure: I am new to the Service Fabric development. Here is my situation. We have Service Fabric Cluster. We deployed stateful service there. Service has designated Service Bus queue, which it listens to. So all service instances on all nodes in the cluster listening to the same Service Bus queue. Each service instance register OnMessage callback with the Service Bus queue to process message like this:

```
  QueueClient Queue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
                                 GetServicebusConnectionString(), 
                                 ConfigData.SERVICE_QUEUE_NAME);
   if (Queue != null)
   {
       var options = new OnMessageOptions();
       options.AutoComplete = false;

       Queue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) => 
                          ProcessMessage(receivedMessage), options);
   }
```

Now, according to messages in the log it looks like all service instances pick up message, that has been placed in the queue simultaneously. Which does not constitute a good thing.
Question is:

> Is it possible to use Service Bus queue in a way when each message from the queue would be picked up only by one service instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [receive mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#receive-mode) of queue client is **PeekLock**, and you set **AutoComplete** property to false, which will not automatically delete message after the client has received the message. After the lock expires, the message will become available again, and other service instances could receive and process it again.

> Is it possible to use Service Bus queue in a way when each message from the queue would be picked up only by one service instance?

You could set AutoComplete property to true, or call [Complete method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0) after the client has received and processed the message.

```
Queue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
                { ProcessMessage(receivedMessage); receivedMessage.Complete(); }, options);
```

Comment: Well, it was my blinder. I've been calling Abandon method thinking it would be sending message to the dead letter queue.:)  When I switched to Deadletter method everything magically started to make sense again. Thank you for helping me getting on the right track.